# truffle: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable' address payable []array; ^-----^ Compilation failed

Tags: truffle-compile

While compiling in truffle I got an error because of payable modifier. If I remove payable then there's no error. But I want to use payable. Can anyone please help me?

error:

```
truffle(develop)> compile
Error parsing /contracts/test.sol: ParsedContract.sol:3:13: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable'
    address payable []array;
```

contract is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract test{
    address payable []array;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK only a function can be payable, not a field.

Comment: @ivicaa: Starting from solc 0.5.x (used in Truffle 5.x onward as the default compiler), a state variable (of type `address` if I recall correctly) can be declared `payable`.

Comment: @goodvibration ah! Got it. Payable address has the transfer function.

Answer (score 1):

The `payable` modifier for addresses is only available from solc v0.5.xx. It is a measure to ensure safe use of transfer when only it is needed.

This compiles and work with solc v0.5.xx and fails with v0.4.xx.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract test{
    address payable []array;
}
```

If you target solc v0.4.xx then it is not required and the code should work without it. The only disadvantge is the compiler will not warn you when you make a transfer.

This programs works with solc v0.4.xx.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract test{
    address []array;
}
```

Comment: That does not provide an to the question though (why the compilation error).

Comment: @goodvibration It compiles correctly with solc v0.5 and fails with solc v0.4 because it is an invalid syntax.